# How to send a value from D3 node to Servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, d3.js

I have an application where i am populating a tree like structure with D3.js.Each node in this tree represents a name.I am able to catch the nodes name in a java script alert when i am clicking on the node .But my requirement is that i should send the name, which is coming with an alert to a Servlet.Here is my code

```
.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var width = 300;
    height = 500;

    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

    d3.json("ActionServlet", function(error, root) {
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
        links = cluster.links(nodes);            


        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

        node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5);

        node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        function click(d){
            alert("This Number is: "+d.name);
        }

    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```

I want the value in the ActionServlet which i am using to create a json.somebody please help.[image: This is the structure i am using and this is the alert in which i am showing the value]

Comment: What is the problem you are having in communicating with the servlet? Do you need help in making an AJAX call to your serve{-r,-let}?

Comment: can you help me with that??my code is there

Comment: function doajax(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ActionServlet",
                        type: "post",
                        data: { "mobileNo":name },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("error occured!!!");
                        } i am doing this but not working

Comment: _Not working_ is a very weak evidence to work on. What happens when you do this? Where do you do this? Does the console show any errors? Is this function called at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your click function with this-

```
 function click(d){               
           var name=d.name;               
               $.ajax({
                   url: "ActionServlet",
                   type: "post",
                   data: { "root":name },
                   error:function(){
                       alert("error occured!!!");
                   },
                   success:function(d){
                       //alert(d.name);
                   }
               });

       }

   });
```